# Itchy trigger finger

Tags: discussion

This question was closed just a few minutes after being asked:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56734/marketing-director-that-needed-to-come-up-with-a-phrase-to-sell-a-womans-produc

Honestly, if that description wasn't sufficient, you might not want to moderate a movie site.  We need to do better with closing some of these questions, I've seen it before but refrained from bringing it up.

How can we ensure that mods aren't pulling the plug too quickly?  Are you communicating with each other via the chat room?  On the music site, we have a mod chat room and we check with each other to see what we think before making rash decisions.  Remember, a mod can close a question with one click.  That power needs to be wielded with some judiciousness.

Comment: *"must contain sufficient detail **to meet the site's quality standards**"* (which are explained in our guides). Nowhere does it say "to identify the film" anymore. I'm afraid we've been over this many times: it's not about *answerablity* but *quality*, and knowing the answer doesn't make the question any better. "What's the crime comedy with a pregnant cop in the snow thanks" can be identified in a second, but that doesn't mean I want these sort of 1-2 liners cluttering up the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is wrong with my identify question?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2151/49), [Why are movie and TV show identification questions so underrated?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2179/49), [What happens to identification questions that don't have sufficient details, but are answerable nevertheless?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2050/49) and [Bad policing and constant down-voting of questions with the identify-this-movie tag](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2328/49).